# How do i animate the opacity of an element when scrolling is selected?

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I'm at the very beginning of learning JS, right now what's bugging me is I want to animate the opacity of a div when scrolling is detected
I have 2 options from what i've found online:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll',function());
```

or

```
window.onscroll()=function();
```

Using the first variant, and the console, I see it is detecting the scrolling but here comes my trouble.

Let:

```
let loadingscreen=document.getElementsByTagName('div')[3];
loadingscreen.style.opacity="0";
```

Why won't this work?

```
window.addEventListener('scroll',()=>{
console.log("!"); //detecting the scroll in the console
setInterval(function(){loadingscreen.style.opacity+=".1"},100);});`
```

The opacity only changes once, i believe it is from 0 to 0.1

Is it that my opacity goes from 0 to 0.1 to 0.11 to 0.111? Tho i cant understand why that would be.
Thank you for taking your time to read this, any response is apreciated!!

I know the code doesn't look that tidy, i promise it is better in my vsc, im having a little trouble with stackoverflow

Comment: Do you want to change the opacity continuously once the user has started to scroll or do you want it to just go up a little bit on each scroll start or should it be proportional to the amount scrolled?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are adding a string to a string, not a number to another number. If you want to add 0.1 of opacity when scrolling is detected, you would have to parse the opacity value with `parseInt(loadingscreen.style.opacity)`, then add 0.1 and then apply it to `loadingscreen.style.opacity`.

However:

> scroll events can fire at a high rate

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event

So, if you scroll one time, your event-handler will maybe fire 20 times, and everytime there is an eventlistener added. So, first you should add `{ once: true }` to your eventListener options.

Secondly, you are adding more opacity every 100 milliseconds.

If you want a nice animation, you should add a class and animate the opacity in CSS.

Consider the following example:

```js
let loadingscreen = document.querySelector(".loadingscreen");

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  loadingscreen.classList.add("scrolled");
}, {
    once: true
}
);
```

```css
body {
  height: 200vh;
}

div.loadingscreen {
  margin-top: 25%;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0;
}

div.loadingscreen.scrolled {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="loadingscreen"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const loadingscreen = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[2];

loadingscreen.style.opacity= 0;

let incOpa = 0

function callIncOpacity(){
      let refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function(){
        console.log(incOpa); //detecting the scroll in the console
        if(incOpa < 1) {
          incOpa += 0.1;
            loadingscreen.style.opacity = incOpa
        }
      }, 10);
    
    setTimeout(function(){
      clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
    }, 100)
}

window.addEventListener('scroll',()=>{
    
    if(incOpa < 1) callIncOpacity()

});
```

```css
.content-container,
.second-div,
.third-div{
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="content-container">
<p>
Test content
</p>
</div>

<div class="second-div">
<p>
test content 1
</p>
</div>

<div class="third-div">
<p>
test content 2
</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Two things to be kept in mind.

1. Style property can't be incremented
2. When you call the setInterval at some point it's better to stop it once the job is done.